# spring configuration with outside config file

Tags: java, spring, configuration

in my applicationContext.xml I have this

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:#{ systemProperties['outsideConfigFile'] }" />
```

And I start my tomcat with -DoutsideConfigFile=/path/to/my/file.properties (verified)

This does not seem to work, and I get

```
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from URL [file:#{ systemProperties['outsideConfigFile'] }]
```

and then

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (No such file or directory)
```

does anyone have anyideas how to get it to work? I think the issue is that spring is not able to read the given system property file.

Thanks a lot
-- MB

Comment: Explain what you mean by it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: What does "does not seem to work" mean? You get an exception? Spring doesn't load? Spring says the property has no value?

Comment: update the question, sorry, good point.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that your file path syntax is wrong. Read the **Table 4.1. Resource strings** section of this [tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/resources.html) and pay attention to [4.7.3. FileSystemResource caveats](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/resources.html#resources-filesystemresource-caveats)

Answer (score 0):

As Spring is indicating, it is unable to find the file.

Try using:  -DoutsideConfigFile=file:/path/to/my/file.properties as per [Spring Resource Loader](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader) docs.

Answer (score 0):

What about using ${}? Since it's a System property, it's available immediately unlike properties loaded from an external file. Have you tried that?